# Is it possible to turn display_errors off in the ini file if you have shared hosting?

Tags: php, security

(Why am I getting a warning that my question is subjective?) I'm trying to keep PHP error messages from being displayed to the browser while debugging.  The two methods I have found to do this are 
1)

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0)
```

and 2) adding a

```
php_flag display_errors Off
```

in the .htaccess file in my document root.  The ini_set command returns null, and the .htaccess setting doesn't have any effect after I upload it.  I am able to direct the error to a custom error handling function, but I'm just unable to keep it from displaying to the screen.

The ISP that hosts my site is unable to help me with this.  I think that I might have to live with errors displaying while I'm debugging, but I'm hoping someone out there might have an alternative way of suppressing the display.

Comment: You should not ask us, but the shared hoster you're planning to use. Different hoster, different way to configure php.ini. For the overview, the manual outlines everything: http://php.net/ini / http://php.net/configuration

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` will suppress errors from being displayed

Comment: as @hakre writes, but I would use ini_set to give my application control of displaying errors. You don't now when your hosting company decides to change some configuration which turns on or off the paramater you used to have set.

Comment: I do want to quietly report errors, though.  This is a question my hoster wants to charge me extra to answer!

Comment: You may consider changing your hosts. A hoster, that doesn't want to disable displaying errors in production, seems not very reliable ;)

Comment: Many hosting companies provide access to the web server log-files containing the PHP output. If not and you are using your own code, you could create an small Log class to handle all application logging, but you need to handle all exceptions in your code though. Some PHP applications might also have their own log functionality which you might be able to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not what you want in the long term, but maybe useful as a makeshift solution. If you prefix PHP function calls with @, they won't output warnings.

Example:

```
<?php
explode(":", $undefinedVariable); // will warn about undefined variable
@explode(":", $undefinedVariable); // will be silent

// It works also for array access etc.:
$foo = array('bar' => 5);
echo 10 * $foo['baz']; // warns
echo 10 * @$foo['baz']; // silent
?>
```

Comment: Or do it right: `isset($foo['baz']);` The first case doesn't exists in clean code. However, I guess the question is more about _real_ errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the PHP code below to turn off error reporting.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

As for quietly logging errors, try this instead.

```
ini_set('log_errors', E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); // you can change error types here.
ini_set('error_log', 'DIRECTORY OF ERROR LOG'); // change as required
```